# How to break on every method of a class in GDB?

Tags: c++, class, gdb

I have a class with a regrettable number of methods.  I would like gdb to break whenever I enter the class, so through any of the methods.  Is there a way to do this without setting break points individually for each method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I never tried it myself, but it seems you can try the [`rbreak`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) command :

> rbreak *regex*
>
> Set breakpoints on all functions matching the regular expression regex. This command sets an unconditional breakpoint on all matches, printing a list of all breakpoints it set. Once these breakpoints are set, they are treated just like the breakpoints set with the break command.

Comment: `rb regex` for short